# Access all of the data after joining two tables and group them using linq

Tags: c#, linq, join, linq-group

I have two tables

```
TableA
aId
aValue

TableB
bId
aId
bValue
```

I want to join these two tables via `aId`, and from there, group them by `bValue`

```
var result = 
from a in db.TableA
join b in db.TableB on a.aId equals b.aId
group b by b.bValue into x
select new {x};
```

My code doesn't recognize the join after the group.  In other words, the grouping works, but the join doesn't (or at least I can't figure out how to access all of the data after the join).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The expression between the `group` and the `by` creates the group elements.

```
var result =  
from a in db.TableA 
join b in db.TableB on a.aId equals b.aId 
group new {A = a, B = b} by b.bValue;

  // demonstration of navigating the result
foreach(var g in result)
{
  Console.WriteLine(g.Key);
  foreach(var x in g)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(x.A.aId);
    Console.WriteLine(x.B.bId);
  }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a freakin' charm!  Thanks so much! :D

Comment: I was always missing the `new {A = a, B = b}` part...Works great, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your `result` object will be an `IQueryable<IGrouping<T>>`, so you'd have to access one of the results collection, which will be `IGrouping<T>`, and then dig into *that* collection to get the `x` objects.